# Copying files/folders on all drives to an external drive?

Tags: batch-file

So, I need to backup about a dozen old computers in the office and there's no network set up that is currently available. I plan on getting everything onto an external HDD and I usually just use the following for the same.

```
xcopy C:\ F:\Backup /D /E /Y /EXCLUDE:BackupExclude.txt
```

The above assumes that C:\ is the drive from which files/folders need to be backed up and F:\ is the external HDD. I'm looking for a way to automate the same.

I want a batch script that enumerates every partition of all available drives on a system, and uses **xcopy** to copy everything to the particular external HDD in a directory named after the computer's name and with subdirectories for each partition/logical drive.

I want the batch script to recognize the external HDD using its serial number.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well here is a starting point for you.  This should do everything you asked.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Loop through all of the drives to find the external HDD
for %%D in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    for /f "tokens=5" %%S in ('vol %%~D:') do set "xSerial=%%S"
    if "%xSerial%"=="ABCD-1234" (
        rem TODO Specify the target copy base location
        set "xTarget=%%~D:\%ComputerName%"
    )
)

rem Loop through all of the drives, skipping the external HDD
for %%D in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    for /f "tokens=5" %%S in ('vol %%~D:') do set "xSerial=%%S"
    if not "%xSerial%"=="ABCD-1234" (
        pushd "%%~D:\" 2>nul
        if !ErrorLevel! EQU 0 (
            mkdir %xTarget%\%%~D
            xcopy "%%~D:\" "%xTarget%\%%~D" /D /E /Y /EXCLUDE:BackupExclude.txt
        )
        popd
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```